# libsgx_capable.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: c, shared-libraries, sgx

I am trying to run the following code in order to enable SGX in my machine (BIOS: software controlled):

```
//enable_device.c
#include "stdio.h"
#include "sgx_capable.h"
#include "sgx_eid.h"
#include "sgx_urts.h"
#include "sgx_error.h"

int main(void) {
        sgx_device_status_t sgx_device_status;
        sgx_status_t ret;

        ret = sgx_cap_enable_device(&sgx_device_status);

        if(ret == SGX_SUCCESS) {
                switch(sgx_device_status) {
                        case SGX_ENABLED:
                                printf("The platform is enabled for Intel SGX.\n$
                                break;
                        case SGX_DISABLED_REBOOT_REQUIRED:
                                printf("This platform is disabled for Intel SGX.$
                                break;
                        case SGX_DISABLED_MANUAL_ENABLE:
                                printf("The platform is disabled for Intel SGX b$
                                break;
//                      case SGX_DISABLED_HYPERV_ENABLED:
//                              printf("The detected version of Windows* 10 is i$
//                              break;
                        case SGX_DISABLED_LEGACY_OS:
                                printf("The operating system does not support UE$
                                break;
                        case SGX_DISABLED_UNSUPPORTED_CPU:
                                printf("Intel SGX is not supported by this proce$
                                break;
                        case SGX_DISABLED:
                                printf("This platform is disabled for Intel SGX.$
                                break;
                        default:
                                printf("UNKNOWN RESPONSE\n");
                }
        } else {
                switch(ret) {
                        case SGX_ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER:
                                printf("The sgx_device_status pointer is invalid$
                                break;
                        case SGX_ERROR_NO_PRIVILEGE:
                                printf("The application does not have the requir$
                                break;
//                      case SGX_ERROR_HYPERV_ENABLED:
//                              printf("The detected version of Windows* 10 is i$
//                              break;
                        default:
                                printf("An unexpected error is detected.\n");
                }
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Here is the Makefile I am using:

```
######### SGX TOOLS ######################
SGX_SDK := /usr/local/lib/intel/sgxsdk
SGX_LIBRARY_PATH := $(SGX_SDK)/lib64

######## App Settings ########
App_C_Files := enable_device.c
App_C_Flags := -fPIC -Wno-attributes -IInclude -IApp -I$(SGX_SDK)/include
App_Cpp_Flags := $(App_C_Flags) -std=c++11
App_Link_Flags := -L$(SGX_LIBRARY_PATH) -lsgx_capable
App_C_Objects := $(App_C_Files:.c=.o)
App_Name := app

.PHONY: all run

all: $(App_Name)

run: all

######## App Objects ########

enable_device.o: enable_device.c
        @$(CC) $(App_C_Flags) -c $< -o $@

$(App_Name): enable_device.o
        @$(CC) $^ -o $@ $(App_Link_Flags)

.PHONY: clean

clean:
        @rm -f $(App_Name) $(App_C_Objects)
```

When I run the application, I receive this message:

> The application does not have the required privileges to read an EFI variable. Run the application with the administrator privileges to enable the Intel SGX device status.

Then, I run `sudo ./app` and receive the following error:

> ./app: error while loading shared libraries: libsgx_capable.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

The strange thing is that this library is not being found when compiling:

```
$ldd app 
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe065bc000)
libsgx_capable.so => not found
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f15a060d000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f15a0c01000)
```

Then, I use:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/intel/sgxsdk/lib64/
```

I run again and the same error message returns. Can anyone tell what I am missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The strange thing is that this library is not being found when compiling.

It *is* being found when compiling (actually, when linking). Otherwise the
linkage of `app` would fail and it would not exist. The `ldd app` output:

```
libsgx_capable.so => not found
```

shows that the *linker* found `libsgx_capable.so`, and duly wrote a `NEEDED`
entry for it in the `.dynamic` section of `app`, which `ldd` - invoking the
runtime loader - attempts resolve to an actual file, and cannot resolve because
the *loader* cannot now find `libsgx_capable.so` in any of the directories where it always looks:

1. The `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` directories
2. The [`ldconfig`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ldconfig) cache directories listed in `/etc/ld.so.conf`
3. The trusted directories `/lib` and `/usr/lib`

That is because `/usr/local/lib/intel/sgxsdk/lib64/` is not one of directories **2** or
**3** and is not one of directories **1** at the moment when you run `ldd app`.

You say that `app` requires root privilege and you run it with `sudo ./app`,
but even when you execute:

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/intel/sgxsdk/lib64/
$ sudo ./app
```

you still encounter:

```
./app: error while loading shared libraries: libsgx_capable.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This happens because the `sudo` command does not by default pass the environment in which it
is called to the commands that it executes as root. See:

```
$ cat main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char const *foobar = getenv("FOOBAR");
    printf("FOOBAR=[%s]\n",foobar ? foobar : "<null>");
    return 0;
}

$ gcc -Wall -o prog main.c
$ export FOOBAR=foobar
$ ./prog
FOOBAR=[foobar]
$ sudo ./prog
FOOBAR=[<null>]
```

To transmit environment settings through `sudo` you can pass them as parameters
to `sudo`:

```
$ sudo FOOBAR=barfoo ./prog
FOOBAR=[barfoo]
$ echo $FOOBAR
foobar
```

or you can give the option `-E` to `sudo`:

```
$ sudo -E ./prog
FOOBAR=[foobar]
```

So either:

```
$ sudo LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/intel/sgxsdk/lib64/ ./app
```

or:

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/intel/sgxsdk/lib64/
$ sudo -E ./app
```

will work. You may prefer however not to depend on `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to
let `app` load `libsgx_capable.so` at runtime. In that case you can get it into
the `ldconfig` cache by running:

```
$ sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib/intel/sgxsdk/lib64/
```

which will cache any shared libraries in `/usr/local/lib/intel/sgxsdk/lib64/`
for the loader.

Or, if you would rather keep your `ldconfig` cache as your distro defined it,
you can just change:

```
App_Link_Flags := -L$(SGX_LIBRARY_PATH) -lsgx_capable
```

to:

```
App_Link_Flags := -L$(SGX_LIBRARY_PATH) -lsgx_capable -Wl,-rpath=$(SGX_LIBRARY_PATH)
```

in your makefile. That will make the linker add a `RUNPATH` entry to the `.dynamic`
section in `app` prompting the loader to search `/usr/local/lib/intel/sgxsdk/lib64/`
for needed libraries after directories **1** and before directories **2** and **3**.

Comment: You could also use `sudo -E $command`  to pass the environment through.

Comment: @EmployedRussian Yes. Incorporated.

Comment: Thank you for this amazing explanation, clarifying all the points.